# Change Database login Cred in PowerBI Online report (.pbix)

Tags: azure, powershell, powerbi

We need to Publish reports (.pbix)  to multiple workspaces, so I am trying to user Powershell to automate this. 
We have PowerBI online.
My database is Azure SQL server.

Now same pbix should be published to different workspaces so I thought of using powershell and change some details in powershell before publish.

---

I tried look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/setalldatasetconnectionsingroup

I managed to change the Server, Database, but seems Cred (user/ pwd) does not change

Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=myDataBase;User ID=mylogin@myserver;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;
is sample connectionstring I am using.

My Report is using DirectQuery Mode.

---

Then I also tried change Mode to Import and try use api:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/updateparametersingroup

for this I added parameters in my report. Seems again Server, Database name can be changed.  but NOT userid, password. I could see updated Server, Database name only in Parameters using PowerBI Desktop-->Workspace--> Report-->.